# derivative of cost function for Logistic Regression

Tags: statistics, regression, machine-learning, partial-derivative

I am going over the lectures on Machine Learning at Coursera.

I am struggling with the following. How can the partial derivative of

$$J(\theta)=-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y^{i}\log(h_\theta(x^{i}))+(1-y^{i})\log(1-h_\theta(x^{i}))$$

where $h_{\theta}(x)$ is defined as follows

$$h_{\theta}(x)=g(\theta^{T}x)$$
$$g(z)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}$$

be $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}J(\theta) =\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(h_\theta(x^{i})-y^i)x_j^i$$

In other words, how would we go about calculating the partial derivative with respect to $\theta$ of the cost function (the logs are natural logarithms):

$$J(\theta)=-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y^{i}\log(h_\theta(x^{i}))+(1-y^{i})\log(1-h_\theta(x^{i}))$$

Comment: I think to resolve $\theta$ by gradient will be hard way (or impossible??). Because it different with linear classfication, it will not has close form. So i suggest you can use other method example [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). BTW, do you find $\theta$ using above way?

Comment: missing $\frac{1}{m}$ for the derivative of the Cost

Answer (score 173, accepted):

The reason is the following. We use the notation:

$$\theta x^i:=\theta_0+\theta_1 x^i_1+\dots+\theta_p x^i_p.$$

Then

$$\log h_\theta(x^i)=\log\frac{1}{1+e^{-\theta x^i} }=-\log ( 1+e^{-\theta x^i} ),$$ $$\log(1- h_\theta(x^i))=\log(1-\frac{1}{1+e^{-\theta x^i} })=\log (e^{-\theta x^i} )-\log ( 1+e^{-\theta x^i} )=-\theta x^i-\log ( 1+e^{-\theta x^i} ),$$ [ this used: $ 1 = \frac{(1+e^{-\theta x^i})}{(1+e^{-\theta x^i})},$ the 1's in numerator cancel, then we used: $\log(x/y) = \log(x) - \log(y)$]

Since our original cost function is the form of:

$$J(\theta)=-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y^{i}\log(h_\theta(x^{i}))+(1-y^{i})\log(1-h_\theta(x^{i}))$$

Plugging in the two simplified expressions above, we obtain
$$J(\theta)=-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \left[-y^i(\log ( 1+e^{-\theta x^i})) + (1-y^i)(-\theta x^i-\log ( 1+e^{-\theta x^i} ))\right]$$, which can be simplified to:
$$J(\theta)=-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \left[y_i\theta x^i-\theta x^i-\log(1+e^{-\theta x^i})\right]=-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \left[y_i\theta x^i-\log(1+e^{\theta x^i})\right],~~(*)$$

where the second equality follows from

$$-\theta x^i-\log(1+e^{-\theta x^i})=
-\left[ \log e^{\theta x^i}+
\log(1+e^{-\theta x^i} )
\right]=-\log(1+e^{\theta x^i}). $$ [ we used $ \log(x) + \log(y) = log(x y) $ ]

All you need now is to compute the partial derivatives of $(*)$ w.r.t. $\theta_j$. As
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}y_i\theta x^i=y_ix^i_j, $$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}\log(1+e^{\theta x^i})=\frac{x^i_je^{\theta x^i}}{1+e^{\theta x^i}}=x^i_jh_\theta(x^i),$$

the thesis follows.

Comment: AHAHAH :D I hope it helps! Feel free to upvote it, if it was useful. Next step:  maximum entropy principle computation leading to the logistic regression? ;-)

Comment: Can't upvote as I don't have 15 reputation just yet! :) Will google the maximum entropy principle as I have no clue what that is! as a side note I am not sure how you made the jump from log(1 - hypothesis(x)) to log(a) - log(b) but will raise another question for this as I don't think I can type latex here, really impressed with your answer! learning all this stuff on my own is proving to be quite a challenge thus the more kudos to you for providing such an elegant answer! :)

Comment: Do you mean $\log(1-h_\theta)=\log(1-\frac{1}{1+e^{-\theta x^i}})=...$? The equality follows from the definition of $h_\theta$, and the rest from the property of logarithms: $\log(\frac{a}{b})=\log a-\log b$.

Comment: yes!!! I couldn't see that you were using this property $\log(\frac{a}{b})=\log a-\log b$ Now everything makes sense :) Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Awesome explanation, thank you very much! The only thing I am still struggling with is the very last line, how the derivative was made in $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}\log(1+e^{\theta x^i})=\frac{x^i_je^{\theta x^i}}{1+e^{\theta x^i}}$$ ? Could you provide a hint for it? Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: In the last line, I understand the differential operation, but don't get the simplification to xi * h θ (x)

Comment: @codewarrior hope this helps.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}\log(1+e^{\theta x^i})=\frac{x^i_je^{\theta x^i}}{1+e^{\theta x^i}} $$
$$     = \frac{{x^i_j}}{{e^{-\theta x^i}*(1+e^{\theta x^i})}} $$
$$     
=\frac{{x^i_j}}{{e^{-\theta x^i}+e^{-\theta x^i + \theta x^i}}} $$
$$     
=\frac{{x^i_j}}{{e^{-\theta x^i}+e^{0}}}
$$
$$     
=\frac{{x^i_j}}{{e^{-\theta x^i}+1}}
$$
$$     
=\frac{{x^i_j}}{{1+e^{-\theta x^i}}}
$$
$$     
=x^i_j*h_\theta(x^i)  $$
 
as 
$$ h_\theta(x^i) = \frac{{1}}{{1+e^{\theta x^i}}}
$$

Comment: please ignore the last line error as it should be 

$$ h_\theta(x^i)= \frac{{1}}{{1+e^{-\theta x^i}}} $$

Comment: why does i go from being a superscript to a subscript?

Comment: I have asked something similar to this question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2143966/193243. I don't know why they use the **Second formula** in Udacity. Are **First Formula** and **Second Formula** equivalents?

Comment: @Rudresh, how are you getting to: $$= \frac{{x^i_j}}{{e^{-\theta x^i}*(1+e^{\theta x^i})}}$$
?
I posted a more detailed question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198487/how-do-i-calculate-the-partial-derivative-of-the-logistic-sigmoid-function

Comment: @devinbost you still have doubt??? take $$e^{\theta x }$$ from numerator to denominator

Comment: @Rudresh, I was misreading your comment.

Comment: Why:
$\log (e^{-\theta x^i} )-\log ( 1+e^{-\theta x^i} )=-\theta x^i-\log ( 1+e^{-\theta x^i} )$ ?
logaritm is base 10 not base e.

Comment: @Israel, logarithm is usually base e in math. Take a look at [When log is written without a base, is the equation normally referring to log base 10 or natural log?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293783/when-log-is-written-without-a-base-is-the-equation-normally-referring-to-log-ba)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer - I've found it really useful. I'm just checking does $$-\left[ \log e^{\theta x^i}+
\log(1+e^{-\theta x^i} )
\right]=-\log(1+e^{\theta x^i}). $$ or $$ -\left[ \log e^{\theta x^i}+
\log(1+e^{-\theta x^i} )
\right]=\theta x^i-\log(1+e^{\theta x^i}). $$. It's the line beginning "where the second equality follows from"

Answer (score 6):

You have to get the partial derivative with respect $\theta_j$. Remember that the hypothesis function here is equal to the sigmoid function  which is a function of $\theta$; in other words, we need to apply the chain rule. This is my approach:

$$J(\theta)=-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y^{i}\log(h_\theta(x^{i}))+(1-y^{i})\log(1-h_\theta(x^{i}))$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}J(\theta) = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}} [-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y^{i}\log(h_\theta(x^{i}))+(1-y^{i})\log(1-h_\theta(x^{i})) ]$$

Anything without $\theta$ is treated as constant:

$$ \tag{1} \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}J(\theta) =  
-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y^{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}[\log(h_\theta(x^{i}))]+(1-y^{i})\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}[\log(1-h_\theta(x^{i})) ]$$

Let's solve each derivative separately and then plug back in on (1):

$$\tag{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}[\log(h_\theta(x^{i}))] = \frac{1}{h_\theta(x^{i})} \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}} h_\theta(x^{i})$$

$$
\tag{3} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}[\log(1 - h_\theta(x^{i}))] = 
\frac{1}{1 - h_\theta(x^{i})} \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}} (1 -h_\theta(x^{i})  = 
\frac{-1}{1 - h_\theta(x^{i})} \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}} h_\theta(x^{i})
$$

Plug (3) and (2) in (1):

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}J(\theta) =  
-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y^{i}
\frac{1}{h_\theta(x^{i})}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}} h_\theta(x^{i})
+(1-y^{i})
\frac{-1}{1 - h_\theta(x^{i})} \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}} h_\theta(x^{i})
 ]$$

$$\tag{4} \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}J(\theta) =  
-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}
[
\frac{y^{i}}{h_\theta(x^{i})}
-
\frac{(1-y^{i})}{1 - h_\theta(x^{i})} 
 ] *
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}} h_\theta(x^{i})$$

Notice that using the chain rule, the derivative of the hypothesis function can be understood as 
$$\tag{5}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}[\ h_\theta(x^{i})]  =  
\frac{\partial}{\partial z }[\ h(z)]  *
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}[\ z(\theta)] =  [h(z) * [1 -  h(z) ]] *[x_j^i]
$$

where

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z }[\ h(z)] = \frac{\partial}{\partial z } \frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}
= \frac{0 - (1)*(1+e^{-z})'}{(1+e^{-z})^2}
= \frac{ (e^{-z})}{(1+e^{-z})^2}
= [\frac{1}{(1+e^{-z})}] * [\frac{ (e^{-z})}{(1+e^{-z})}]
= [\frac{1}{(1+e^{-z})}] * [1 -\frac{1}{(1+e^{-z})}] =  h(z) * [1 -  h(z) ]
$$
and 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}[\ z(\theta)]  = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}[\ \theta x^i] = x_j^i $$

Plug (5) in (4):

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}J(\theta) =  
-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}
[
\frac{y^{i}}{h_\theta(x^{i})}
-
\frac{(1-y^{i})}{1 - h_\theta(x^{i})} 
 ] *
 [ h_\theta(x^{i}) * ( 1 -h_\theta(x^{i}))  *  x_j^i ]$$

Applying some algebra and solving subtraction:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}J(\theta) =\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(h_\theta(x^{i})-y^i)x_j^i$$

There is a $1/m$ factor missing on your expected answer.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

@pedro-lopes, it is called as: [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).
$$(u(v))' = u(v)' * v'$$
For example:
$$y = \sin(3x - 5)$$
$$u(v) = \sin(3x - 5)$$
$$v = (3x - 5)$$
$$y' = \sin(3x - 5)' = \cos(3x - 5) * (3 - 0) = 3\cos(3x-5)$$

Regarding: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}\log(1+e^{\theta x^i})=\frac{x^i_je^{\theta x^i}}{1+e^{\theta x^i}}$$
$$u(v) = \log(1+e^{\theta x^i})$$
$$v = 1+e^{\theta x^i}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\log(1+e^{\theta x^i}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\log(1+e^{\theta x^i}) * \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(1+e^{\theta x^i}) = \frac{1}{1+e^{\theta x^i}} * (0 + xe^{\theta x^i}) = \frac{xe^{\theta x^i}}{1+e^{\theta x^i}} $$
Note that $$\log(x)' = \frac{1}{x}$$
Hope that I answered on your question!

Answer (score 4):

We have,
\begin{align*}
L(\theta) &= -\frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}{y_i. log P(y_i|x_i,\theta)  + (1-y_i). \log{(1 - P(y_i|x_i,\theta))}} \\
h_\theta(x_i) &= P(y_i|x_i,\theta) = P(y_i=1|x_i,\theta) = \frac{1}{1+\exp{\left(-\sum\limits_k \theta_k x_i^k \right)}}
\end{align*}

Then,
\begin{align*}
\log{(P(y_i|x_i,\theta))}=\log{(P(y_i=1|x_i,\theta))} &=-\log{\left(1+\exp{\left(-\sum\limits_k \theta_k x_i^k \right)} \right)} \\
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_j} log P(y_i|x_i,\theta) =\frac{x_i^j.\exp{\left(-\sum\limits_k \theta_k x_i^k\right)}}{1+\exp{\left(-\sum\limits_k \theta_k x_i^k\right)}} &= x_i^j.\left(1-P(y_i|x_i,\theta)\right) \end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\log{(1-P(y_i|x_i,\theta))}=\log{(1-P(y_i=1|x_i,\theta))} &=-\sum\limits_k \theta_k x_i^k -\log{\left(1+\exp{\left(-\sum\limits_k \theta_k x_i^k \right)} \right)} \\
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_j} \log{(1 - P(y_i|x_i,\theta))} &= -x_i^j + x_i^j.\left(1-P(y_i|x_i,\theta)\right) = -x_i^j.P(y_i|x_i,\theta) \\ 
\end{align*}

Hence,

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_j} L(\theta) &= -\frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}{y_i.\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_j} log P(y_i|x_i,\theta)   + (1-y_i).\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_j} \log{(1 - P(y_i|x_i,\theta))}} \\
&=-\frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}{y_i.x_i^j.\left(1-P(y_i|x_i,\theta)\right) - (1-y_i).x_i^j.P(y_i|x_i,\theta)} \\
&=-\frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}{y_i.x_i^j - x_i^j.P(y_i|x_i,\theta)} \\
&=\frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}{(P(y_i|x_i,\theta)-y_i).x_i^j}
\end{align*} (Proved)

Comment: The logistic regression implementation with gradient-descent using this derivative can be found here: https://sandipanweb.wordpress.com/2017/11/25/some-deep-learning-with-python-tensorflow-and-keras/

Comment: what about w.r.t to b?

Comment: We can include the bias term $\theta_0$ inside $\theta$ if we extend $x_i$ as $(1,x_i)$, i.e., by adding a column of 1 s with x.

Answer (score 3):

Pedro,
 => partial fractions

$$\log(1 - \frac{a}{b})$$

$$1 - \frac{a}{b}  =  \frac{b}{b} - \frac{a}{b}  =  \frac{b-a}{b},$$
$$\log(1 - \frac{a}{b}) = \log(\frac{b-a}{b}) = \log(b-a) - \log(b)$$

Answer (score 3):

$${ 
J(\theta)=-\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{m} y^i\log(h_\theta(x^i))+(1-y^i)\log(1-h_\theta(x^i)) 
}$$
where $h_\theta(x)$ is defined as follows
$${
h_\theta(x)=g(\theta^Tx),
}$$
$${
g(z)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}
}$$
Note that $g(z)'=g(z)*(1-g(z))$ and 
we can simply write right side of summation as 
$${
y\log(g)+(1-y)\log(1-g)
}$$
and the derivative of it as
$${
y \frac{1}{g}g'+(1-y) \left( \frac{1}{1-g}\right) (-g') \\
=\left(  \frac{y}{g}-  \frac{1-y}{1-g}\right) g' \\
= \frac{y(1-g)-g(1-y)}{g(1-g)}g'  \\
= \frac{y-y*g-g+g*y}{g(1-g)}g'  \\
= \frac{y-y*g-g+g*y}{g(1-g)}g(1-g)*x  \\
=(y-g)*x
}$$

and then we can rewrite above as
$${
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}J(\theta) =\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(h_\theta(x^{i})-y^i)x_j^i
}$$

Comment: In your derivation, from where did you get "x". I mean , you replaced g' with g(1-g)*x but g' = g(1-g) right ? from where "x" come into picture

Answer (score 1):

Notice that,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}y_i\theta x^i = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}y_i(\theta_0 + \theta_1x^i_1 + ... + \theta_jx^i_j)= $$
in this $\partial\theta_j$ order derivative, $y_i$ is a constant, so 
$$=y_i\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}(\theta_0 + \theta_1x^i_1 + ... + \theta_jx^i_j)=$$
because it is a linear model ($\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}k\theta = k$), so
$$=y_i(0 + x^i_1 + ... + x^i_j)=$$
$$=y_ix^i_j$$
Finally,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}y_i\theta x^i = y_ix^i_j$$

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}\def\J{{\cal J}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Bigl(#1\Bigr)}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\diagb#1{\operatorname{diag}\BR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diagb#1{\operatorname{Diag}\BR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$For ease of typing, replace the Greek symbol $(\theta\to w)\,$
and collect all of the $x_k$ vectors into a matrix, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
X = {\tt[}x_1\;x_2\ldots\,x_m {\tt]} \\
}$$
What you have called $g(z)$ is actually the logistic function which has a [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Derivative) derivative
$$\frac{dg}{dz} = (1-g)\,g \qif dg = (1-g)\,g\;dz$$
When applied elementwise to the vector argument $(X^Tw),\,$
it produces a vector result
$$\eqalign{
h &= g(X^Tw) \\
dh &= \LR{\o-h}\odot h\odot d(X^Tw) \\
  &= \LR{\o-h}\odot h\odot (X^Tdw) \\
}$$
where $(\odot)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product.

But a Hadamard product with a vector can be replaced by the standard product by using a diagonal matrix created from the vector. Therefore
$$\eqalign{
H &= \Diag h &\qif h = \diag H = H\o \\
dh &= \LR{I-H}HX^Tdw &\qif
\grad hw = \LR{I-H}HX^T \\
}$$
The cost function can now be expressed in a *purely* matrix form
$$\eqalign{
Y &= \Diag y \\
\J &= -\fracLR 1m\BR{Y:\log(H)+(I-Y):\log(I-H)} \\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the Frobenius inner product
$$A:B = \trace{A^TB} = \trace{AB^T}$$
Since diagonal matrices are almost as easy to work with as scalars,
it becomes a rather straightforward if tedious exercise to calculate
the gradient
$$\eqalign{
d\J &= -\fracLR 1m\BR{Y:d\log(H)+(I-Y)\,:\,d\log(I-H)} \\
 &= -\fracLR 1m\BR{Y:H^{-1}dH \;-\; (I-Y)\,:\,(I-H)^{-1}dH} \\
 &= -\fracLR 1m\BR{H^{-1}Y \;-\; (I-H)^{-1}(I-Y)}\,:\,\Diag{dh} \\
 &= -\fracLR 1m\diagb{H^{-1}Y \;-\; (I-H)^{-1}(I-Y)}\,:\,dh \\
 &= -\fracLR 1m\BR{H^{-1}Y \;-\; (I-H)^{-1}(I-Y)}\,\o\,:\,\LR{I-H}HX^Tdw \\
 &= -\fracLR 1mX\LR{I-H}H\BR{H^{-1}Y \;-\; (I-H)^{-1}(I-Y)}\,\o\,:\,dw \\
 &= -\fracLR 1mX\BR{\LR{I-H}Y \;+\; H(Y-I)}\,\o\,:\,dw \\
 &= -\fracLR 1mX\BR{Y-HY \;+\;HY - H}\,\o\,:\,dw \\
 &= -\fracLR 1mX\BR{Y-H}\,\o\,:\,dw \\
 &= +\fracLR 1mX\BR{h-y}\,:\,dw \\
\grad{\J}{w} &= \fracLR 1mX\BR{h-y} \\
}$$