# How to represent the parameters in logistic function

Tags: statistics, partial-derivative, regression, machine-learning

I want to find the parameters in logistic function. I read the guide at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477207/derivative-of-cost-function-for-logistic-regression). It very clear to explain. But it did not has final solution that I need. Now, we will consider a basis logistic function 
$$h_\theta(x^{i})=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\theta_0-\theta_1x}}$$
We want to find $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ subject to minimum cost function
$$J(\theta)=-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y^{i}\log(h_\theta(x^{i}))+(1-y^{i})\log(1-h_\theta(x^{i}))$$

We use the notation

$$\theta x^i:=\theta_0+\theta_1 x^i_1 $$

Then

$$\log h_\theta(x^i)=\log\frac{1}{1+e^{-\theta x^i} }=-\log ( 1+e^{-\theta x^i} ),$$
$$\log(1- h_\theta(x^i))=\log(1-\frac{1}{1+e^{-\theta x^i} })=\log (e^{-\theta x^i} )-\log ( 1+e^{-\theta x^i} )=-\theta x^i-\log ( 1+e^{-\theta x^i} ),$$

and

$$J(\theta)=-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \left[y_i\theta x^i-\theta x^i-\log(1+e^{-\theta x^i})\right]=-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \left[y_i\theta x^i-\log(1+e^{\theta x^i})\right],~~(*)$$

where the second equality follows from

$$-\theta x^i-\log(1+e^{-\theta x^i})=
-\left[ \log e^{\theta x^i}+
\log(1+e^{-\theta x^i} )
\right]=-\log(1+e^{\theta x^i}). $$

All you need now is to compute the partial derivatives of $(*)$ w.r.t. $\theta_j$. 
As

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_J}y_i\theta x^i=y_ix^i_j$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}\log(1+e^{\theta x^i})=\frac{x^i_je^{\theta x^i}}{1+e^{\theta x^i}}=x^i_jh_\theta(x^i), $$

OK, The above steps are correct. But it did not have the solution of $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$. We can take the derivative and put it equal $0$. Namely,

$$\frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial \theta_0}=y-\frac{e^{\theta_0+\theta_1 x}}{1+e^{\theta_0+\theta_1 x}}=0~~(*)$$ 
$$\frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial \theta_1}=yx-\frac{xe^{\theta_0+\theta_1 x}}{1+e^{\theta_0+\theta_1 x}}=0 ~~(**) $$
$(*)$ and (**) are they correct?
Assume that $y$ and $x$ are known. How to represent $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ by $y$ and $x$ . Thank you so much