# what is the detailed procedure about the likelihood can be represented as the conditional probability.

Tags: machine-learning

I am learning this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2076936/673047)

here is a formula about the likelihood of single data point

$$ P(y_i ) = h_{\theta}(\mathbf{x}_i)^{y_i} (1 - h_{\theta}(\mathbf{x}_i))^{1-y_i}$$

> $P(y_i)$ is known as the likelihood of single data point
>   $\mathbf{x}_i$,  i.e. given the value of $y_i$  what is the
>   probability of $\mathbf{x}_i$ occurring. it is the conditional
>   probability $P(\mathbf{x}_i | y_i)$.

what is the detailed procedure about the likelihood can be represented as  the conditional probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the explanation you linked to has an error at this point. (This is surprising because the answer you linked to has 17 upvotes.)  I would say that 
$$
P(y_i \mid x_i) = h_\theta(x_i)^{y_i }(1-h_\theta(x_i))^{1-y_i}.
$$
The feature vectors $x_i$ are given, and the observed data are the corresponding *labels* $y_i$. We choose $\theta$ to make the likelihood of the observed *labels* as large as possible.

The likelihood of the observed labels is 
\begin{align}
L(\theta) &= P(y \mid x) \\
&= \Pi_{i=1}^n P(y_i \mid x_i) \\
&=\Pi_{i=1}^n h_\theta(x_i)^{y_i }(1-h_\theta(x_i))^{1-y_i}.
\end{align}
The log-likelihood function is
$$
\log L(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \log(h_\theta(x_i)) + (1-y_i) \log(1-h_\theta(x_i)).
$$
We choose $\theta$ to maximize $\log L(\theta)$.

I think the post you linked to did not explain that part correctly.