# Probability notation semicolon and vertical line

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, notation, conditional-probability

While going through one of the answer I came across the following notation

> $P( y_i =1 \mid \mathbf{x}_i ; \theta)$

I am not sure about its interpretation and how should it be read.

The exact usage can be found   [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886555/deriving-cost-function-using-mle-why-use-log-function)

> Now logistic regression says that the probability that class variable value $y_i =1$ , $i=1,2,...m$ can be modelled as follows
>
> $$
> P( y_i =1 \mid \mathbf{x}_i ; \theta) = h_{\theta}(\mathbf{x}_i) = \dfrac{1}{1+e^{(- \theta^T \mathbf{x}_i)}}
> $$
>
> so $y_i = 1$ with probability $h_{\theta}(\mathbf{x}_i)$ and $y_i=0$ with probability $1-h_{\theta}(\mathbf{x}_i)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: It is just saying this is  the conditional probability that $y_i=1$ given the parameter $\mathbf \theta$ and the values of the independent variables in $\mathbf x_i$