# Cost function vs. MLE

Tags: probability

Occasionally, one can see the following expression called cost function:

$$J(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}y^{i}\log(h_\theta(x^{i}))+(1-y^{i})\log(1-h_\theta(x^{i}))$$.

It looks to be me like maximum likelihood expression. I think it is incorrect to refer to maximum likelihood express as a cost function. They are different. Am I right?

**Update** In my view cost function is squared deviation or something similar 
$$\sum_i (x_i - y_i)^2$$

Here are a couple of links regarding maximum likelihood called cost function:
[Cost1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477207/derivative-of-cost-function-for-logistic-regression)
[Cost2](http://feature-space.com/en/post24.html)

Comment: could you add a reference to your cost function? alternatively add an explanation of what it actually consists

Comment: no they are different only if the random variable model used for the MLE is corresponds EXACTLY to the reality of how the datas were generated. In nearly every case, that probabilistic model is only a model to approximate the way the datas were generated, it's exactly equivalent to give an a priori bigger cost to some values, and lesser to others, which is a cost function.

Comment: and there is a theorem : for every cost function, it exists a probabilistic model such that the minimization of the cost function is equivalent to the maximization of the likelihood given that probabilistic model. thus choosing a cost function is 100% equivalent to choosing a probabilistic model (and thus a MLE)

Comment: the quadratic cost functions are the logarithm of the likelihood of some gaussian probabilistic model for the datas. (one indepedant multi dimensional and indentically distributed gaussian variable, correlated in a linear way)

Comment: @reuns. Thank you very much! Could you give me a reference to theorem establishing connection between maximum likelihood and cost function. I am not grasping how likelihood is related to Gaussian distribution. It looks like the above expression is from binomial distribution.

Comment: try to connect a quadratic function to the correlation matrix of a multidimensional variable, you'll get the theorem for that case. for the general case just keep in mind that the log of a probability distribution is not so constrained : for every function $f(x)$ on $[a;b]$ there exits a probability distribution $P(x)$, non-zero only on $[a;b]$ such that $\ln P(x) = f(x)+a$.

Comment: @reuns, thank you again. I am trying to think through your answer. Is $P(x) =  P([a,x])$. Probably, there are some regularity conditions should be imposed on $f(x)$, such monotonicity?