# Partial derivative in gradient descent for logistic regression

Tags: partial-derivative, gradient-descent

I post this question here because I think this is a calculus problem

I'm a software engineer, and I have just started a Udacity's nanodegree of deep learning.

I have also worked my way through Stanford professor Andrew Ng's [online course on machine learning](http://cs229.stanford.edu) and now I'm comparing.

I have a big doubt about Gradient Descent with sigmoid function because on Andrew Ng's course it is different from the one I see on Udacity's nanodegree.

From Andrew Ng's course, gradient descent is (**First formula**):
[image]

But, from Udacity's nanodegree is (**Second formula**):

[image]

**Note**: first picture is from this [video](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/MtEaZ/simplified-cost-function-and-gradient-descent), and second picture is for this other [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sxA5Ap8AWM).

But in this [CS229 course notes](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf) from Andrew Ng's, on page 18, I have found the demonstration from Andrew Ng's gradient ascent formula. I only add it here as a demonstration because I haven't found this derivative process for gradient descent and I don't know how to do it:
[image]

**Note**: the formula above is for Gradient Ascent.

I'm not sure if I have understood everything, but in this derivative I see have the derivative from `f` function disappears (f function is the sigmoid function).

But in Udacity's nanodegree they continue using the sigmoid's derivative in their gradient descent.

The difference between **first formula** and **second formula** is the derivative term.

Are the two formula equivalents?
Where can I find all partial derivative steps for that partial derivative?

Comment: The first picture maximizes the log-likelihood of the data and the second picture minimizes the squared loss function. In short the difference is because of different objectives.

Answer (score -3):

Please take a look at this part of Machine learning course on Coursera which can help you with your question:
https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/MtEaZ/simplified-cost-function-and-gradient-descent
In this part, the lecturer is showing the result of derivative in gradient descent for logistic regression.