# Second derivative of the cost function of logistic function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, regression, machine-learning

Do I have the correct solution for the second derivative of the cost function of a logistic function?

Cost Function
$$J(\theta)=-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y^{i}\log(h_\theta(x^{i}))+(1-y^{i})\log(1-h_\theta(x^{i}))$$

where $h_{\theta}(x)$ is defined as follows

$$h_{\theta}(x)=g(\theta^{T}x)$$
$$g(z)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}$$

[First Derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477207/derivative-of-cost-function-for-logistic-regression) 
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}J(\theta) =\sum_{i=1}^{m}(h_\theta(x^{i})-y^i)x_j^i$$

Second Derivative 
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial^2\theta_{j}}J'(\theta) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(h_\theta(x^{i})x_j^i -y^ix^i_j) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(h_\theta(x^{i})x_j^i) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{x^{i}}{1+e^{-z}} \\
&= x^2 h_\theta(x) ^2
\end{align*} 
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For convenience, define some variables and their differentials
$$\eqalign{
 z &= X^T\theta, &\,\,\,\, dz = X^Td\theta \cr
 p &= \exp(z), &\,\,\,\, dp = p\odot dz  \cr
 h &= \frac{p}{1+p}, &\,\,\,\, dh = (h-h\odot h)\odot dz \,= (H-H^2)\,dz \cr
}$$
where 

$\,\,\,\,H={\rm Diag}(h)$

$\,\,\,\,\odot$ represents the Hadamard elementwise product

$\,\,\,\,\exp$ is applied elementwise

$\,\,\,\frac{p}{1+p}$ represents elementwise division

The cost function can be written in terms of these variables and the Frobenius inner product (represented by a colon) 
$$\eqalign{
 J &= -\frac{1}{m}\Big[y:\log(h) + (1-y):\log(1-h)\Big] \cr
}$$

The differential of the cost is
$$\eqalign{
dJ &= -\frac{1}{m}\Big[y:d\log(h) + (1-y):d\log(1-h)\Big] \cr
   &= -\frac{1}{m}\Big[y:H^{-1}dh - (1-y):(I-H)^{-1}dh\Big] \cr
   &= -\frac{1}{m}\Big[H^{-1}y - (I-H)^{-1}(1-y)\Big]:dh \cr
   &= -\frac{1}{m}\Big[H^{-1}y - (I-H)^{-1}(1-y)\Big]:H(I-H)dz \cr
   &= -\frac{1}{m}\Big[(I-H)y - H(1-y)\Big]:dz \cr
   &= -\frac{1}{m}(y-h):X^Td\theta \cr
   &= \frac{1}{m}X(h-y):d\theta \cr
}$$
The gradient
$$\eqalign{
G =\frac{\partial J}{\partial\theta} &= \frac{1}{m}X(h-y) \cr
}$$
(NB:  Your gradient is missing the $\frac{1}{m}$ factor)

The differential of the gradient
$$\eqalign{
dG &= \frac{1}{m}X\,dh \cr
   &= \frac{1}{m}X(H-H^2)\,dz \cr
   &= \frac{1}{m}X(H-H^2)X^T\,d\theta \cr\cr
}$$
And finally, the gradient of the gradient (aka the Hessian)
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial^2J}{\partial\theta\,\partial\theta^T} &=
\frac{\partial G}{\partial\theta} = 
\frac{1}{m}X(H-H^2)X^T \cr
}$$

Comment: by `Diag(h)` you mean Diagonal Matrix of h ?