# Why are terms flipped in partial derivative of logistic regression cost function?

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, machine-learning

When calculating the partial derivative:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}J(\theta) $$
from:
$$ J(\theta)=-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y^{i}\log(h_\theta(x^{i}))+(1-y^{i})\log(1-h_\theta(x^{i})))$$
with:
$$h_{\theta}(x)=g(\theta^{T}x)$$
and
$$g(z)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}$$
as documented in the question here: [Derivative of cost function for logistic regression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477207/derivative-of-cost-function-for-logistic-regression)
(Note: Some of my content is taken from that post.)

So, how are we deriving:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}J(\theta) =\sum_{i=1}^{m}(h_\theta(x^{i})-y^i)x_j^i$$
rather than:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}J(\theta) =\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y^i - h_\theta(x^{i}))x_j^i$$
? 
When I work it out, I get the latter, rather than the former.

Here's my work (attempted proof):

Let $$a = \log(h_\theta(x^i))$$
and $$ b=\log(1-h_\theta(x^i))$$
Then,

$$ J(\theta)=-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y^{i} a+(1-y^{i}) b)$$

We can then simplify a:
$$a = \log(h_\theta(x^i)) $$
$$= \log(\frac{1}{1+e^{-\theta x^i}})$$
$$= \log(1) - \log(1+e^{-\theta x^i}) $$
$$= 0 - \log(1+e^{-\theta x^i}) $$
$$= -\log(1+e^{-\theta x^i})$$

and since $$1 = \frac{(1+e^{-\theta x^i})}{(1+e^{-\theta x^i})}$$

we can simplify b:

$$b = \log(1-h_\theta(x^i)) $$
$$= \log(1 - \frac{1}{(1+e^{-\theta x^i})}) $$
$$= \log(\frac{(1+e^{-\theta x^i})}{(1+e^{-\theta x^i})} - \frac{1}{(1+e^{-\theta x^i})}) $$
$$= \log(\frac{(1+e^{-\theta x^i}) - 1}{(1+e^{-\theta x^i})}) $$
$$= \log(\frac{1-1+e^{-\theta x^i}}{(1+e^{-\theta x^i})})$$
$$= \log(\frac{0+e^{-\theta x^i}}{(1+e^{-\theta x^i})})$$
$$= \log(\frac{e^{-\theta x^i}}{(1+e^{-\theta x^i})}) $$
$$= \log(e^{-\theta x^i}) - \log(1+e^{-\theta x^i})$$
$$= -\theta x^i - \log(1 + e^{-\theta x^i}) $$

by associativity, simplifying by common denominators, evaluating the logarithm on e, and the logarithm property that $$\log_b(M/N) = \log_b(M) - \log_b(N)$$

Thus, we simplified to:
$$a = -\log(1+e^{-\theta x^i})$$
and 
$$b = -\theta x^i - \log(1 + e^{-\theta x^i})$$

Let us then set:
$$t = \log(1 + e^{-\theta x^i})$$
so that:
$$a = -t$$
and 
$$b = -\theta x^i - t$$

We may then substitute:
$$ J(\theta)
=-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y^{i}\log(h_\theta(x^{i}))+(1-y^{i})\log(1-h_\theta(x^{i}))) $$
$$= -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y^i a + (1 - y^i) b)) $$
Expanding to t, we then get:
$$J(\theta)
=-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y^i (-t) + (1 - y^i) (-\theta x^i - t))
= -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(-t y^i + (1 - y^i) (-\theta x^i - t))
$$
This allows us to expand via FOIL since:
$$ (1 - y^i) (-\theta x^i - t) = (-\theta x^i + \theta x^iy^i - t + ty^i)$$

So,
$$J(\theta)
= -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(-ty^i + (-\theta x^i + \theta x^iy^i -t + ty^i))$$
 and again by associativity:
$$J(\theta)
= -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(-ty^i + ty^i + -\theta x^i + \theta x^iy^i -t )$$
$$
= -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(0 + -\theta x^i + \theta x^iy^i -t )$$
$$
= -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(-\theta x^i + \theta x^iy^i -t )$$

Now we can expand t back out to reduce further because

$$ -\theta x^i = \log(e^{-\theta x^i})$$
and
$$ -\theta x^i = -\log(e^{\theta x^i})$$

So,
$$J(\theta)
= -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(-\theta x^i + \theta x^iy^i -  \log(1 + e^{-\theta x^i}) )$$

$$ = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(-\log(e^{\theta x^i}) + \theta x^iy^i -  \log(1 + e^{-\theta x^i}))$$

$$ = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\theta x^iy^i + (-\log(e^{\theta x^i})) - \log(1 + e^{-\theta x^i}))$$

$$ = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\theta x^iy^i + (-[\log(e^{\theta x^i}) + \log(1 + e^{-\theta x^i})]))$$

and since:
$$ \log(M) + \log(N) = \log(MN)$$

we can apply the distributive property and simplify the bracketed term:
$$ [\log(e^{\theta x^i}) + \log(1 + e^{-\theta x^i})] $$
$$= \log(e^{\theta x^i} * (1 + e^{-\theta x^i}) $$
$$= \log(e^{\theta x^i} + (e^{\theta x^i} * e^{-\theta x^i} )) $$
$$= \log(e^{\theta x^i} + (e^{(\theta x^i) + (-\theta x^i)} ))$$
$$= \log(e^{\theta x^i} + (e^{0} ))$$
$$= \log(e^{\theta x^i} + (1) )$$
$$= \log(e^{\theta x^i} + 1 )$$

Substituting the simplified bracketed term back in:
$$J(\theta)
= -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\theta x^iy^i + (-[\log(e^{\theta x^i} + 1 )]))$$

and dropping the extra brackets and parentheses:

$$J(\theta)
= -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\theta x^iy^i -\log(e^{\theta x^i} + 1 ))$$

Next, calculating the partial derivatives:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} (\theta x^i y^i)= x^i_j y^i $$
because the corresponding theta component becomes 1 and drops out. Then, let:

$$ s = \theta x^i$$
$$ r = 1 + e^{s} $$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} (\log(r)) 
= \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial s} \frac{\partial s}{\partial \theta_j} (\log(r))$$
So,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(\log(r))
 = \frac{1}{r} $$
(since we're really referring to the natural log, ln)
and 
$$ \frac{\partial r}{\partial s} = e^s$$
and
$$ \frac{\partial s}{\partial \theta_j} = x_j^i $$
because the theta component again becomes 1 and drops out.
So, by the chain rule and substitution:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}(\log(r)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial s} \frac{\partial s}{\partial \theta_j}$$
$$= \frac{1}{r} e^s x_j^i $$
$$= \frac{1}{1 + e^{s}} e^s x_j^i $$
$$= \frac{1}{1 + e^{\theta x^i}} e^{\theta x^i} x_j^i$$
$$= \frac{e^{\theta x^i} x_j^i}{1 + e^{\theta x^i}}$$
We can then move the e term from the top to the bottom and apply the distributive property again to simplify:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} (\log(r)) = \frac{x_j^i}{e^{-\theta x^i} (1 + e^{\theta x^i})}$$
$$= \frac{x_j^i}{(e^{-\theta x^i} + e^{-\theta x^i} * e^{\theta x^i})}$$
and then using exponent multiplication rules:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} (\log(r))  = \frac{x_j^i}{(e^{-\theta x^i} + e^{(-\theta x^i) + (\theta x^i)})}$$
$$= \frac{x_j^i}{(e^{-\theta x^i} + e^{(0)})}$$
$$= \frac{x_j^i}{(e^{-\theta x^i} + 1)}$$
$$= \frac{x_j^i}{(1 + e^{-\theta x^i})}$$

By using the notation from the link above:
$$ \theta x^i:=\theta_0+\theta_1 x^i_1+\dots+\theta_p x^i_p. $$
Resolving:
$$ h_\theta(x^i) = g(\theta^T x^i) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-\theta x^i}} $$
and then factoring out:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}(\log(r)) = \frac{x_j^i}{(1 + e^{-\theta x^i})} = x_j^i \frac{1}{(1 + e^{-\theta x^i})} = x_j^i h_\theta(x^i)$$

So, our inner partial derivatives are:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} (\theta x^i y^i)= x^i_j y^i$$
and
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}(\log(e^{\theta x^i} + 1)) = x_j^i h_\theta(x^i)$$

So, for J:
$$ J(\theta)
= -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\theta x^iy^i -\log(e^{\theta x^i} + 1 ))$$
computing the partial derivative:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}(J(\theta)) 
= -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} (\theta x^i y^i) - \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}(\log(e^{\theta x^i} + 1))) $$
$$ = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(x^i_j y^i - x_j^i h_\theta(x^i))$$
which we can factor:
$$ = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}((y^i - h_\theta(x^i))x^i_j)$$

and yet the course instructor obtained:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_{j}}J(\theta) =\sum_{i=1}^{m}(h_\theta(x^{i})-y^i)x_j^i $$

How is this possible?

Comment: In your final result bring the minus sign inside the parentheses?

Comment: @xidgel Oh my gosh.... I can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer is that the course instructor brought the minus sign inside the parentheses. Thanks to @xidgel for noticing it!
So,
$$-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}((y^i - h_\theta(x^i))x^i_j)$$

$$= \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(-(y^i - h_\theta(x^i))x^i_j)$$
$$= \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}((-y^i + h_\theta(x^i))x^i_j)$$
$$= \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}((h_\theta(x^i)-y^i)x^i_j)$$

Also, when I took a closer look at the instructor's derivative, contrary to what was posted in [Derivative of cost function for Logistic Regression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477207/derivative-of-cost-function-for-logistic-regression/477261?noredirect=1#comment4525785_477261), the instructor's term did still have the $$\frac{1}{m}$$ in front of the sum. But it was positive, not negative.