# Need help with logarithmic inequality.

Tags: inequality, logarithms

We want to find the least $n$ that satisfies this inequality: 
$$
\frac{4 n}{ \log (4 n)} > \frac{90 n  \log (113)}{113 \log (3 n)}.
$$
We divide each side by $\frac{4 n}{ \log (3 n)}$ to move $n$ to LHS and $4$ to RHS,
$$
\frac{ \log (3 n)}{ \log (4 n)}>\frac{45  \log (113 )}{226}.
$$
Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica reduce to,
$$
n>3^{\frac{226}{45  \log (113)-226}} e^{-\frac{90 \log (2 )  \log (113)}{45  \log (113)-226}},
$$
but I have no idea how to get there.

Are there any logarithmic identities that would help?

Comment: logarithms are decimal or natural?

Comment: @leonbloy, natural. Naturally.

Comment: Naturally... up to a point. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293783/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $n\ge 1$ and calling $A=\frac{226}{45  \log (113 )}\approx 1.062$ we have

$$ 
\begin{align}
\frac{4 n}{ \log (4 n)} > \frac{90 n  \log (113)}{113 \log (3 n)}
 & \iff A \log 3n  > \log 4n \\
 & \iff  \log (3n)^A  > \log 4n \\
 & \iff (3n) ^A>4n\\ 
& \iff n^{A-1}> 4/3^A  \\ & \iff n>(4/3^A)^{1/(A-1)}\approx 33.5855
\end{align}
$$

Hence the least integer that verifies the inequation is $n=34$

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to separate a $\log n$ from everything else by multiplying both sides by $\log 4n$ and then using $\log ab = \log a + \log b$. From there, just solve for $\log n$ and then just $n$.