# Upper bound number of distinct prime factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-factorization

I want to prove that if $\omega (n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ for $n>2$ we have $\omega (n) \leq \frac{\ln n}{\ln \ln n} + O(\frac{\ln n}{(\ln \ln n)^2})$.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is a standard result - see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23867/bound-on-the-number-of-prime-factors-of-logarithmically-rough-numbers. Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179353/effective-upper-bound-for-the-number-of-prime-divisors and the proof by Robin.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Ramanujan_theorem

Comment: Well okay I now know that this is a standard result. Nevertheless I can't find a proof...So maybe someone can help me?

Comment: Noone? - maybe you can help me out with an english translation of the proof by Robin?

Answer (score 10):

$\omega(n)$ reaches a maximum at the primorial numbers $p\#=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\cdots\cdot p,$ where $\omega(p\#)=\pi(p).$ The Prime Number Theorem (in one of its forms) says that $\vartheta(x):=\log x\#\sim x,$ and so $p\#=e^{(1+o(1))p}$. If $p$ is the $n$-th prime then $p\sim n\log n$ and so
$$
n=\pi(p)=\omega(p\#)=\omega(e^{(1+o(1))p})=\omega(e^{(1+o(1))(1+o(1))n\log n})=\omega(n^{(1+o(1))n}).
$$

Setting $x=n^{(1+o(1))n}$ and solving for $n$ you get
$$
n\sim\frac{\log x}{W(\log x)}=\frac{\log x}{W(\log x)}=\frac{\log x}{\log\log x-O(\log\log\log x)}\sim\frac{\log x}{\log\log x}
$$
which has a slightly weaker error term than the quoted result.

Comment: The observation that $\omega(n)$ reaches a maximum at the primorial number is very impressive.

Answer (score 1):

One can use the fact that $w(n) \leq \sum _{d|n} \frac{\Lambda (d)}{\log d}$ and it can be shown that for any $x$ we've $\sum _{d|n} \frac{\Lambda (d)}{\log d} \leq \frac{\log n}{\log x}+ O(\frac{x}{(\log x)^2})$ and now we just need to take $x=\log n$