# Upper bound for count of unique prime divisors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Suppose $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I am trying to find an explicit upper bound for the number of prime factors of $n$ as a function of $n$.
I know similar problems have been asked before ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938204/upper-bound-number-of-distinct-prime-factors), for example) but I am trying to do another approach.

Here is my proof so far.
Every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ can be written as a product of primes:
\begin{equation}
 n = p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_k^{\alpha_k}.
\end{equation}
Trivially, we can see that $n$ has $k$ prime factors.
Let $\omega(n)=k$.
$\omega(n)$ is maximized if $n$ is a product of consecutive primes,
or $n=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\dots\cdot p$,
where $\omega(n)=\pi(p)$.
According to the Prime Number Theorem, we have that 
\begin{equation}
\omega(n)=\mathcal{O}\bigg(\frac{p}{\ln p}\bigg).
\end{equation}

I don't know where to go from here. I know that the result is supposed to be $$\frac{\ln n}{\ln(\ln n)}$$ but this means that $p\approx\ln n$ and I am unsure of how to show that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good start! (One should rigorously prove that it suffices to look at the product of the first several primes.) The other piece of information you need is that
$$
\log n = \log\bigg( \prod_{q\le p} q \bigg) = \sum_{q\le p} \log q = \theta(p)$$
(where $q$ denotes a prime variable); and the prime number theorem tells us then that $\log n \sim p$. That's how $\frac p{\log p}$ gets transformed into $\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}$.