# If $|G_{2n}| \geq 2$ for all $n \geq 4$, does it imply Goldbach's Conjecture? My Conjecture onto proving Goldbachs Conjecture.

Tags: group-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

Let's look some definitions before we start.

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $G_n := \{\text{primes } p : p \nmid n \, \wedge \, p<n\}$. Let $U(n)$ be group of units of the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ where $(n) := \{nm : m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. More specifically, $U(n) := \{m \in \mathbb{Z}^+ : 1 \leq m \leq n \, \wedge \, \gcd(m,n) = 1\}$ and the binary opertion is multiplication modulo $n$.

I noticed that $U(n)$ contains some nice properties. Notice that if $m \in U(n)$ (hence, $\gcd(m,n)=1$ and $1 \leq m \leq n$), then $\gcd(m,n-m) = 1$. This property is true because one can use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. This implies, that one can always find a pair of numbers $(p,q) \in U(n) \times U(n)$ such that $p+q = n$. In particular, $|U(n)|$ is always even for all $n \geq 3$. This is not a surprise since by definition the Euler's totient function $\varphi(n) = |U(n)|$, for which it has a lot of properties found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

I was wondering that if $G_{2n}$ is nonempty for all $n \geq 2$, then Goldbach's Conjecture is true? In particular, $|G_{2n}| \geq 2$. I was thinking about this because for all positive integers $n$, we have $G_{n} \subsetneq U(n)$.

To prove that $G_n \subsetneq U(n)$, we notice that if $n = 1$ or $2$, $G_n = \varnothing \subsetneq U(n)$ since there no primes that are less than $n$. All is left to show is that $$\forall n \forall p \,\, (n \geq 3 \,\, \& \,\, p\in G_n \Longrightarrow \gcd(n,p) = 1 \,\, \& \,\, 1\leq p \leq n)$$ By definition of $G_n$, if $p \in G_n$, then $p$ is prime. Hence, $1< 2 \leq p < n$. So, $1\leq p \leq n$. Also, since $p$ is prime and $p \in G_n$, we have the $$p \nmid n \iff \gcd(p,n) =1$$

Summary: I was wondering that if $|G_{2n}| \geq 2$ for all $n \geq 4$, then Goldbach's Conjecture is true just by using the fact that $G_n \subsetneq U(n)$ by searching primes $(p,q) \in G_{2n} \times G_{2n}$ such that $p+q = 2n$?

Edit: My hypothesis is that my conjecture is nothing compared to the actual Goldbach's Conjecure. That is, we need more than just verifying if one set is a subset of another set.

Comment: Not following.  $G_{2n}$ will be quite large, in general.  After all, it surely contains all the primes between $n$ and $2n$, so it has more that $\pi(2n)-\pi(n)$ elements.  Not seeing the connection to Goldbach.  Or have I misread the definitions?

Comment: @lulu, let me explain. I was thinking that since $U(n)$ has the property that there exists a pair $(r,s) \in U(n)$ s.t. $n = r+s$, maybe one can find a pair of primes $(p, q) \in G_{2n} \times G_{2n}$, such that $p + q = 2n$? Let me edit my post again.

Comment: Well, I don't see it.  As I say, $G_{2n}$ will be quite large.  [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938204/upper-bound-number-of-distinct-prime-factors) together with the prime number theorem let you estimate $|G_{2n}|$.  But, again, I don't think this will help with Goldbach.

Comment: @lulu I agree. Maybe I was thinking so randomly and just thought of this conjecture as if  it would be so simple to prove the Goldbachs's Conjecture, you know? Lol. Regardless, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are solving $p+q=n$ for $p,q\in U(n)$ and hoping to translate this into a solution with $p,q\in G_n$ which, if this worked for all even $n$, would prove Goldbach's conjecture. Now it is true that the equation has solutions with $p,q\in U(n)$, for instance $p=1$ and $q=n-1$, but there is no obvious way to turn this into a solution for $p,q\in G_n$.