# Upper Bund number of prime divisors counted with multiplicity

Tags: number-theory

In the answers of another question ([Effective Upper Bound for the Number of Prime Divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179353/effective-upper-bound-for-the-number-of-prime-divisors)) I found the following proposition:

The number of prime divisors counted with multiplicity is maximized for powers of $2$ and so

$$\Omega(n)\le\frac{\log n}{\log 2}=\log_2 n$$

Can someone give me a formal proof for this?

Comment: Well, that's obvious. For any number $n$ with any prime divisors, changing them all to 2 will result in a smaller $n$ with the same $\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you. I‘m not a native speaker and thought powers of 2 meant raising all the prime devisors to the power of 2.